# Front end login: Redirect to user created post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Is is possible to redirect a user on front end login to a post that they have created? If so how?

I have the form below on the front end which works great to log people in but doesn't quite achieve what I want.

I've created a front end registration process, that creates a new user and a post and fills in certain details into that post. On completion of that process they are sent to the post they just created, which then allows them to front end edit all the details. That works perfectly for first time registrants but I can't quite achieve what I want with people that have already registered and want to login.

When they fill in their details on the form below, I want it to redirect to the post they created when they registered, is this possible?

The users can only ever create **ONE** post... which is acting as a profile. So I want them to be able to log in and get redirected to their profile.

If it helps, the username is the same as the post title (the username is the persons company name, which is also the name of the post). E.g username = My Company. Post title = My Company.

```
            <?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>   
                <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post" id="login-form">
                    <p style="color:black!IMPORTANT;">Please login.</p>
                    <!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" />
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <!--[if (gte IE 6)]>
                        <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="Username" />
                    <![endif]-->
                    <!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <!--[if (gte IE 6)]>
                        <input type="password" value="Password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
                    <![endif]-->    
                    <p style="clear:both;width:115px;font-size:14px!IMPORTANT;float:left;">
                        <input style="width:14%!IMPORTANT;" name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me
                    </p>


                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
                    <p style="float:right;">
                        <a style="font-size:14px!IMPORTANT;" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a>
                    </p>                                
                    <input style="margin-left:80px;float:left;" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" class="login-button" />                               
                </form>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <p>
                    You are currently logged in, would you like to <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">logout</a>?
                </p>
            <?php } ?>
```

I'm guessing the following...

I need to do something with the username (entered in the form above) then match that with the author of any posts, if that matches then send them to that page... all before the submission of the form above. This needs to be done before the hidden field, so it can enter the username field into the hidden input value.

Comment: I hate the question "Is it possible?" as a programmer youll find that anything with a computer is possible, the only question is, "Do I have the time to do it?"

Comment: What problem do you have in rerouting the user inside `wp-login.php` after successful login? You can do a php redirect with [`header(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: @Garreh The hidden field is actually the part that redirects. At the moment it just logs the person in and reloads the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a user can only have **ONE** post, surely you have a link or method to detect that, such as something stored in the database. What you can do is when testing if the credentials are correct, find the link and then override the redirect. You don't need to know the link and hide it before the user even logs in, it's not possible.

Example:

```
<?php
   ...get variables...;
   if( isValidUser()){
      $var = db->getUserPostId();
      $redirect = "posts.php?pid=".$var;
      header("Location: $redirect");
   else
      .. show error and go back..
?>
```

**EDIT:** javascript example

```
<script>
    function onSubmit(){
        document.forms["login"]["redirect_to"].value = document.forms["login"]["log"].value;
    }
</script>
<form name="login" action="test.php" method="post" onsubmit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" name="log">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="start">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

The example will change the value of the hidden field before the form is submitted. You can build the link however you wish, the example only takes the username.

Comment: I have a two step form which will only allow the user to get to the 2nd step if the company name is unique - meaning every single post will have a unique name. In the form in the question - the hidden field is what redirects the user. It needs to have the action set to what it is as Wordpress does some stuff in the background that I don't really want to touch.

Comment: The problem with what you want is that you're going to have to dig into the login code. It's not possible to know who is going to login before they do and therefore can't have the link ready to go. You could find ways to 'guess' but that is not suggested.

Comment: Is there not a way to take the username they entered and put it at the end of the hidden input value via jquery perhaps??? As the username is the same as the post link (as it's the title).

Comment: That pretty much works, thanks. The one thing I need to adjust is to replace white spaces with dashes. Not really sure how to do that so I'll probably ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. You can get the current page's url using php's `$_SERVER` method. Here is a tutorial - **[PHP: How to Get the Current Page URL](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php)**

Then you may pass this data into login form page using `GET` method, so that login page (containing login form) can catch this url. Then you may include this url data in the login form either as a hidden field, or as a part of the action's target php file (like `<form method="post" action="target.php?targeturl=someurl.com/somepage"`) where the form's target script file can read this url. Then after processing login data, the processing script can redirect browser to the target url.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve your problem is that once the user redirected to a particular page e.g, edit post page, or edit profile page. You need to save the URL of the page by session.

```
$_SESSION['refpage'] = getPageUrl(); // this is your function that will return a current page url.
```

After the user logged-in, you check if the session $_SESSION['refpage'] is exist, if found then redirect him e.g redirect("location:".$_SESSION['refpage'])